# I want to populate a model using foreign keys from other models (using select boxes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create an estimate form which happens to be a model. This form has 
Customer info which is a model as well, vehicle information which is another model nested inside customer on resources. Employee name as well(also a model). I want to be able to select using select boxes on customer, which leads me to a list of the customer vehicles and then being able to populate who is the employee performing the estimate also from a list of the model employee. (I am learning ROR as I go so please I apologize the lack of maybe the right lingo to explain: Also Iwas able to be able to generate the select box for the customer but can't go past that. In other words no even able to access the vehicles for each customer on a selet box. Please help.

Models:

```
class Estimate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :vehicle
    belongs_to  :employee
    has_many :lines_in_estimates
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vehicles
    has_many :estimates
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :h_phone, presence: true
    validates :c_phone, presence: true
    validates_format_of :email, with: /\A[\w]([^@\s,;]+)@(([\w-]+\.)+          (com|edu|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info))\z/i

   def first_name_and_last_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
 end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Controller:

```
    class EstimatesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_estimate, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @estimates = Estimate.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @estimate = Estimate.new
    end




    private

        def set_estimate 
             @estimate = Estimate.find(params[:id])
        end

        def set_customer
            @estimate = Estimate.find(params[:id])
        end

        def set_vehicle
            @vehicle = @customer.vehicles.find(params[:id])
        end

        def estimate_params
            params.require(:estimate).permit(:statetax, :muntax, :subtotal,     :total, :created_at, :updated_at, 
                                        :customer_id, :vehicle_id,     :employee_id)
    end

        def customer_params
            params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :addr1,     :addr2, :city, :state, :zip, :h_phone, :c_phone, :email)
    end
end
```

Form:

```
    <%= form_for(@estimate) do |f| %>

    <% if @estimate.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@estimate.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this     employee from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @estimate.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>




  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Choose_Customer %><br> 
    <%= collection_select(:estimate, :customer_id, Customer.all, :id,        :first_name_and_last_name, prompt: true ) %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is saying exactly. Can you give a specific error message thats preventing you from continuing on in your code? Sound like you have a pretty complex domain model. I would take a step back, figure out exactly what it is you need, and then try and scope your question. I think as it stands right now, its too broad.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I am trying to make an estimates feature. I need to be able to create a new estimate being estimate a model ( I need to make reference to customers, their vehicle, and the employee who is preparing the estimate. This info is sitting on other models and what I would like is to give the employee the ability to make an estimate by just selecting the name then of course a list of the (customer's vehicles is going to come up in the list. Of course the estimate needs me to enter the employee who is preparing the estimate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, a customer has many vehicles and a vehicle has many estimates. With setting up your Rails models correctly, you can call `customer.vehicles` to return an array of vehicles owned by that customer. Iterating through that you can then call `vehicle.estimates` to get an array of estimates per vehicle.

```
class Customer << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vehicles
end

class Vehicle << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :estimates
end

class Estimate << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

In your create_table migrations for vehicles and estimates, you need respectively `t.belongs_to :customer` and `t.belongs_to :vehicle` so the foreign keys are created in your db that allow Rails to make the connection.

Use plural names when using `has_many` and when naming your tables.

Once this is set up and working, to get all estimates for a customer, I think all you need to do is add `has_many :estimates, through :vehicles` to your customers model. Which will enable `customer.estimates` to return all estimates. I'm a little less sure of my ground here though so get the rest working first.

Some light reading on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).